# Submit a form to MySQL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to submit a form to my MySQL DB, using jQuery (AJAX). When I press the submit button, I get the failed message "failed" I wrote in JavaScript. I think there is something wrong in my JavaScript syntax.

**HTML/JavaScript**

```
<form method="post" action="opslaan.php">
  <input type="text" id="itmnlid" name="tmnlid">
  <input type="text" id="ibesproken" name="besproken">
  <input type="text" id="iafspraken" name="afspraken">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>

<script>
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
      'opslaan.php', {
        id: $("#itmnlid").val(),
        besproken: $("#ibesproken").val(),
        afspraken: $("#iafspraken").val()
      },
      function(result) {
        if (result == "succes") {
          $("#result").html("succes");
        } else {
          $("#result").html("failed");
        }
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$id = $_POST["id"] ;
$besproken = $_POST["besproken"];
$afspraken = $_POST["afspraken"];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO coaching (id, besproken, afspraken)
VALUES ('$id', '$besproken', '$afspraken')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "succes";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$("form").submit(...)` event is not triggered. You must surround it with `$(document).ready(...)`. Like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        //...
    });
});
```

Otherwise it seems to work.

---

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `coaching` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tmnlid` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `besproken` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `afspraken` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#submit').click(function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'opslaan.php',
                        data: {
                            'tmnlid': $('#tmnlid').val(),
                            'besproken': $('#besproken').val(),
                            'afspraken': $('#afspraken').val(),
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if (response == true) {
                                $('#result').html('Record successfully saved.');
                            } else {
                                $('#result').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            /*
                             * If the status code of the response is a custom one (420 for example),
                             * defined by you in php, then the corresponding error message is displayed.
                             * Otherwise, the displayed message will be a general user-friendly
                             * one - so that no system-related infos will be shown.
                             */
                            var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                    ? jqXHR.statusText
                                    : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                            $('#result').html(message);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>Demo</h3>

        <p id="result"></p>

        <form method="post" action="opslaan.php">
            <label for="tmnlid">Tmnlid:</label>
            <!-- @todo-1 -->
            <input type="text" id="tmnlid" name="tmnlid" maxlength="8"> (max. 8 chars)

            <br/>

            <label for="besproken">Besproken:</label>
            <input type="text" id="besproken" name="besproken">

            <br/>

            <label for="afspraken">Afspraken:</label>
            <input type="text" id="afspraken" name="afspraken">

            <br/>

            <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="save">
                Save
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**opslaan.php:**

```
<?php

require 'handlers.php';
require 'connection.php';

/*
 * =======================
 * Read the posted values.
 * =======================
 */
//@todo-1
$tmnlid = isset($_POST['tmnlid']) ? $_POST['tmnlid'] : '';
$besproken = isset($_POST['besproken']) ? $_POST['besproken'] : '';
$afspraken = isset($_POST['afspraken']) ? $_POST['afspraken'] : '';

/*
 * ===========================
 * Validate the posted values.
 * ===========================
 */
//@todo-1
if (empty($tmnlid)) {
    /*
     * This custom response header triggers the ajax error, because the status
     * code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the client errors). Here is
     * defined "420" as the custom status code. One can choose whatever code
     * between 401-499 which is not officially assigned, e.g. which is marked
     * as "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry. See the link.
     *
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    //@todo-1
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 Please provide the tmnlid.');
    exit();
}
//@todo-1
elseif (strlen($tmnlid) > 8) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 The tmnlid must contain only 8 characters.');
    exit();
}/* Other validations here using elseif statements */

//==================================================
// Here the validations for the other posted values.
// ...
//==================================================

/*
 * ================
 * Save the record.
 * ================
 */
//@todo-1
$sql = 'INSERT INTO coaching (
            tmnlid,
            besproken,
            afspraken
        ) VALUES (
            ?, ?, ?
        )';

/*
 * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

/*
 * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
 * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
 * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
 * or more characters which specify the types for the
 * corresponding bind variables.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
 */
//@todo-1
$statement->bind_param('sss', $tmnlid, $besproken, $afspraken);

/*
 * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
 * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
 * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
 */
$statement->execute();

echo TRUE;
```

**handlers.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * Include this page in all PHP pages of the application.
 *
 * This page contains:
 *  - The APP_ENV constant, used to decide in which environment this application runs.
 *  - The functions for handling all the errors, or exceptions, raised by the application.
 *  - The code for setting them as error/exception handlers.
 *  - The code deciding if the errors should be displayed on the screen. The errors
 *    display MUST be activated ONLY in the development stage of the application. When
 *    the website goes live, ALL ERRORS must be written in a/the log file and NO ERRORS
 *    should be displayed on screen, but only a general, user-friendly message, or a
 *    custom error page.
 */

/*
 * Decide in which environment this application runs. Possible values:
 *  - 'prod' (app in production, e.g. live). The errors are not displayed, but only logged.
 *  - 'dev' (app in development). The errors are displayed on screen and logged.
 *  - 'test' (app in tests). Same as 'dev'.
 *  - etc.
 */
define('APP_ENV', 'dev');

// Activate the errors/exceptions logging.
ini_set('log_errors', 1);

// Set the error reporting level: report all errors.
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Decide how to handle the errors/exceptions.
if (APP_ENV === 'prod') { // App in production, e.g. live.
    /*
     * DON'T display the errors/exceptions on the screen. Just let the error and
     * exception handler print a user-friendly message, or show a custom error page.
     */
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);

    // Set the handler functions.
    set_error_handler('errorHandler');
    set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');
} else { // App in development, tests, etc.
    // Display the errors/exceptions on the screen.
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}

/**
 * Error handler:
 *  - Print a user-friendly message, or show a custom error page.
 *  - Log the error.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php set_error_handler.
 * @param int $errno
 * @param string $errstr
 * @param string $errfile
 * @param int $errline
 */
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo 'An error occurred during your requestsss. Please try again, or contact us.';
    error_log('Error ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errstr . ' in file ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    exit();
}

/**
 * Exception handler:
 *  - Print a user-friendly message, or show a custom error page.
 *  - Log the error.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php set_exception_handler.
 * @param Exception $exception
 */
function exceptionHandler($exception) {
    echo 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
    error_log('Exception ' . $exception->getCode() . ' - ' . $exception->getMessage() . ' in file ' . $exception->getFile() . ' on line ' . $exception->getLine());
    exit();
}
```

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create a new db connection.
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

Comment: You are great!!

Comment: @Marvin I am testing it now.

Comment: Nice im waiting. ;)

Comment: @Marvin I posted it. Take it exactly as it is, paste it in your pages (replace your page contents completely!) and change the db credentials.

Comment: @Marvin In the end, tell me if it works or, if not, why not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176187/discussion-between-marvin-and-dakis).

Comment: @Marvin I reposted the "code version 1" as well. So now are two code versions in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need use `echo` with `json_encode` I think.

json_encode doc: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

And in your POST on JS. use this `json`, like that:

`$.post('endpoint.php', YOUR_DATA_OBJECT, function (result) {
    //something
}, 'json');`

Comment: this doesn't cover the entire problem

Comment: you also need to use English-based links when referencing (external) links.

Comment: ohhh, sorry! json_encode doc to you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: And don't has undefined index `id` too.

Comment: There's nothing in his code that requires the use of JSON.